# jQuery Mobile: Is it possible to have static navigation that doesn't fade with page transitions?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

With jQuery Mobile, is there a way that I can have a navigation bar that takes up 200px (or a percentage) on the left that is separate from the .ui-content div? This would mean the navigation would stay static on the left as the content changes via swiping (transitions).

How would I go about setting this up? I can't find any documentation on editing the content view or how to evade page transitions for certain content!.

[image: example]

The issue with my sample code is that the href links do not link anywhere. They simply do not work. When I put them inside data-role="page", then it works.

```
       <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="one" data-transition="slide">
            <div data-role="content" style="background-color:#ff0;">    
                <h1>One</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /page one -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the CSS for the `data-role="page"` elements to make space for your navigation bar:

```
.ui-mobile [data-role="page"] {
    left : 200px !important;
    width : auto !important;
    right : 0;
}
#leftNav {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 200px;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 100;
}​
```

`#leftNav` is the navigation bar element:

```
<div class="ui-body-a" id="leftNav">
    <a data-direction="reverse" href="#zero">Zero</a>
    <a href="#one">One</a>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j8nkn/2/

It's not perfect, but this should get you started.

Comment: Sorry, I just about to post my sample code (I should have earlier, my apologies). I have that part working, but what doesn't is the actual linking of the navigation, e.g. href="#one" doesn't work outside data-role="page"

Comment: @BrettAlton Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j8nkn/2/. All I did was add buttons to the navigation bar that link to the ID of the page I want to show.

Comment: Ya, as soon as I added buttons to the demo, it worked too. It must be my code that's broken. Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate your time with this.